# Device Busy Error while fetching number plate information using ISAPI Hikvision

Tags: sdk, isapi, automatic-license-plate-recognition, hikvision

I am unable to fetch the number plate info from hikvision video center. I want to access it using the API.

I am getting the response as shown below while fetching the number plate info of vehicle from ANPR Hik vision network video center.

```
<ResponseStatus xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
<requestURL>/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates</requestURL>
<statusCode>2</statusCode>
<statusString>Device Busy</statusString>
<subStatusCode>serviceUnavailable</subStatusCode>
</ResponseStatus>
```

I want the response as shown below.

```
<Plates version="2.0">
    <Plate>
    <captureTime>20340109T094130+0400</captureTime>
    <plateNumber>A 39837</plateNumber>
    <picName>203401090941300600</picName>
    <country>NON</country>
    <laneNo>1</laneNo>
    <direction>reverse</direction>
    <matchingResult>otherlist</matchingResult>
    </Plate>
</Plates>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289875/how-to-get-hikvision-deepinviews-license-plate-number-from-url) thread?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the post command which need the xml body:
https://tpp.hikvision.com/wiki/isapi/anpr/GUID-24DC47D2-14B8-4048-BB90-26746F9C785D.html
it work on my hikvision anpr camera
[image]