# Hikvision DeepView get number plate error on firmware 5.5.8

Tags: automatic-license-plate-recognition, hikvision

I successfully get a number from the Hikvision camera(model iDS-2CD7A26G0/P-IZHS​), the answers from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289875/how-to-get-hikvision-deepinviews-license-plate-number-from-url) helped me. But this solution works for cameras with firmware 5.5.130.
I also have cameras with firmware v5.5.804 build 210831 for which there are no alternative builds.
I get an invalid operation when I try to request a number.

Camera parameters:

Model iDS-2CD7A26G0/P-IZHS
Serial number iDS-2CD7A26G0/P-IZHS20210129AAWRF40749141
firmvare V5.5.804 build 210831
code version: V7.3 build 210806
plagin version 3.0.7.30
firmvare kind C-R-H7-0

For the request I am using the following parameters in postman

url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates
body:

```
<Plates version='2.0' xmlns='http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema'>
    <Plate>
        <captureTime><!— req, xs:datetime —></captureTime>
        <plateNumber><!— req, xs:string —></plateNumber>
        <picName><!— req, xs:string —></picName>
        <country><!— req, xs:string “BLR,….” —></country>
    </Plate>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jkiv.jpg)
</Plates>
```

Authorization: Digest Auth

Integration Protocol Hikvision-CGI diges/basik is enable.

The results are presented in the figures.

[5.5.130 firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg2aa.jpg)

[5.5.8 firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E489H.jpg)

Comment: Did you solve the solution ? i have some problem here

Comment: @BonnyAUlia Hi
I solved this problem. 
I intalled firmware 5.5.130 build 210510. It was work. 
Best regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed firmware 5.5.130 build 210510, which worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35729432)